# Page Will Not Load

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

Running on Heroku and Rails 6.1, I am hitting an issue where a link will not load but from mobile browsers only. It works fine on Desktop browsers. On my login page, I have a link to "apply" which hits a customer devise controller for a new registration.

After tapping apply, the page shows momentarily and then Chrome and Safari both show page load errors:

[image: Safari]

[image: Chrome]

If I go to the URL directly (not tapping the link on the login page), the page loads fine.

My routes look like this:

```html
Rails.application.routes.draw do
  
  resources :applications, only: [:index, :edit, :update]
  get 'profile', to: "profile#show"
  
  devise_for :users, controllers: {
    sessions: 'users/sessions',
    registrations: 'users/registrations'
  }
  
  devise_scope :user do
    
    authenticated :user do
      root 'landing#home', as: :authenticated_root
    end
    
    unauthenticated do
      root 'users/sessions#new', as: :unauthenticated_root
    end

    get "login", to: "devise/sessions#new"
    get "apply", to: "users/registrations#new"
    delete 'logout', to: "devise/sessions#destroy"

  end

end
```

Comment: I put in the address on my phone, got the log in page, then clicked apply and it all worked just fine to show that page.  Chrome and Firefox browsers.  Nothing looks off with your routes. You could open a terminal and from your app directory run `heroku logs --tail` and view what happens when you hit it with your phone

Comment: Hi there, thank you for trying it. By chance, are you on iOS or Android? I have been looking at the logs but have yet to see any errors.

Comment: I have an android.  I assume you are iOs although I'm not really sure what that would matter for something like this.  But I don't know what I don't know.

Comment: When I saw your comment, I pulled out a Google Pixel and it loaded fine! But, the page still won't load on Safari or Chrome on my iPhone or iPad. I'm at a loss!

Answer (score 0):

Finally resolved my issue which had nothing to do with Rails, My Routes, or Heroku. Several fields in the form had: autofocus="" in the input tags. While Mac Safari/Chrome and Android Chrome/Firefox ignored the meaningless tag I suppose, iOS Safari/Chrome would crash.